# Regular Expression - Match only 7 chars?

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to match a SEDOL (exactly 7 chars: 6 alpha-numeric chars followed by 1 numeric char)

My regex

`([A-Z0-9]{6})[0-9]{1}`

matches correctly but strings greater than 7 chars that begin with a valid match also match (if you see what I mean :)). For example:

> B3KMJP4

matches correctly but so does:

> B3KMJP4x

which shouldn't match.

Can anyone show me how to avoid this?

Comment: 4 answers exactly the same, now that's consistency! Thanks to all.

Comment: Apart from the (correct) answers below that you need start/end anchors, you need to remove the space from your first character class (`A A A 0` matches your regex, too). Also (for clarity) remove the unnecessary `{1}`.

Comment: @Tim, I notice all four answers repeat both of the mistakes you pointed out.  You should post your own answer, so Simon can accept that one.

Comment: StackOverflow provides a way to accept the answer that is most helpful, by clicking checkmark next to the answer (as opposed to only indicating so via a comment)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dollar sign at the end of the regex (called an anchor) signifies end of string:

`^([A-Z0-9]{6})\d$`

I also added "^" at the start which signifies start of string and prevents matching xB3KMJP4
I also simplified the original regex.

By the way, as per Wikipedia, for the first character, vowels are not used. I'm not quite sure if that's a rule or a convention.

Comment: I have removed the space as per Tim's comment above (Cut'n'paste - the source of 78.3% of all bugs). BUT... I'm a at a bit of a loss to actually verify whether it is a valid character or not for a SEDOL - "Alphanumeric" can include spaces under some interpretations. I'm inclined to believe that Tim's interpretation is correct.

Comment: I believe this is correct, none of the hundreds of SEDOLs I have listed begin with a vowel char.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use both `start` and `end` `anchors` like this:

```
^([A-Z 0-9]{6})[0-9]{1}$
```

This will match a string which has ***6 alphanumeric+space char followed by one digit***. It does not match if such a string is found as a ***suffix*** or ***prefix*** of a bigger string.

Also you you can get rid of `{1}` because `[0-9]` matches a single digit by itself.

Also `\d` represents a single digit. So you can shorten your regex as follows:

```
^([A-Z \d]{6})\d$
```

Comment: It seems that "A-Z \d" looks less readable and maintanable that A-Z0-9.

Answer (score 3):

```
 ^([A-Z\d]{6})\d$
```

- Use ^ for start of string
- $ for end of string
- Remove extra space,just noticed that one
- Swapped out 0-9 with \d
- Removed {1} since this is redundant

Answer (score 3):

You're forgetting that regex matches anywhere in the string.  To fix it, try this.

```
^([A-Z 0-9]{6})[0-9]{1}$
```

The ^ means to match the beginning of the string, and the $ means to match the end of the string.